# ASP.NET unit testing: where to create/delete test user accounts?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I am new in unit testing. I want to unit test my ASP.NET/MVC application using built-in MS Test.
To perform many tests i need to use temporary user accounts. Where is the best place to put creating/dropping code? I tried to create users in [TestInitialize()] method and put results of type User into class field but it doesnt remain to the moment of the second test s starting :(
Or should i create temp user account in every test method? This doesntlook well...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would normally generate the user accounts into a property of the test during the method with the attribute setup, and delete them in the method marked teardown

```
public UserAccount account { get; set; }

[SetUp]
public void SetUp
{
    // Set up your accounts here
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    account.Delete();
}
```

The attributes ensure that these fixtures are run before and after the test methods.